# I have a logic error, $album_id is always the last value in the albums_table

Tags: php, prepared-statement, html-select

Select statement

```
<?php
$q = $db->prepare( 'SELECT album_id, album_name 
                FROM table_albums ORDER BY album_name' );
$q->bindParam( ':album_id',   $album_id );
$q->bindParam( ':album_name', $album_name );
$q->execute();
```

Just html here

```
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title><?php echo basename( __FILE__ ); ?></title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Add Tracts</h1>

<form method="post">
   Tracks Name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="tracks_name" value="<?php $tracks_name ?>"><br>
   <select>
      <option name="album_id" id="album_id">Select</option>
      <?php while ( $row = $q->fetch() ) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $row->album_id;?>">
```

This is where I think the problem is

```
            <?php echo $row->album_name; $album_id = $row->album_id;?>

         </option>
      <?php } ?>

   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit now"/>
</form>
```

Only process the form if $_POST isn't empty

```
<?php 
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {
   $stmt = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO table_tracks 
                       ( tracks_name,  tracks_id,  album_id ) 
                VALUE  (:tracks_name, :tracks_id, :album_id)" );
   $stmt->bindParam( ':tracks_id',   $tracks_id );
   $stmt->bindParam( ':tracks_name', $tracks_name );
   $stmt->bindParam( ':album_id',    $album_id );
```

insert one row

```
   $tracks_name = $_POST["tracks_name"];
   $stmt->execute();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

album_id is always the last value in the database
I am not sure what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change here also, add `echo`

```
<input type="text" name="tracks_name" value="<?php echo $tracks_name; ?>"><br>
```

And

```
  <select  name="album_id" id="album_id">
  <option value="">Select</option>
```

Your album_id was not submitting ,  we generally give name and id to `select` tag not to `option`.

Answer (score 0):

On the line that you point at, you do assign `$album_id` there but don't use it inside the loop.  So of course the loop will be completed and the last assignment will reflect the last record.

If you need to do something else with it, you either need to place it inside an array, or do the processing while you have the data at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct as to where the problem is.

```
<?php echo $row->album_name; $album_id = $row->album_id;?>
```

`$album_id` is always the last album id in database.
You don't require it.
Just use:

```
<?php echo $row->album_name; ?>
```

Bind the correct variable to `:album_id`:

```
$stmt->bindParam( ':album_id', $_POST['$album_id']);
```

Comment: $_POST only has one element it it.array (size=1)
  'tracks_name' => string 'vvv' (length=3)

Comment: @dgs Because you need to alter your `<select>` to `<select name="album_id">` as @Rishi answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">
   Tracks Name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="tracks_name" value="<?php $tracks_name ?>"><br>
   <select  name="album_id" id="album_id">
      <option value"" >Select</option>
      <?php while ( $row = $q->fetch() ) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $row->album_id;?>">
            <?php echo $row->album_name; $album_id = $row->album_id;?>
         </option>
      <?php } ?>

   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit now"/>
</form>


<?php include '../includes/logout.php';
// Only process the form if $_POST isn't empty
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {
   var_dump( $_POST ) ;
   $stmt = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO table_tracks ( tracks_name,  tracks_id,         album_id ) 
                      VALUE                    (:tracks_name, :tracks_id,   :album_id)" );
   $stmt->bindParam( ':tracks_id',   $tracks_id );
   $stmt->bindParam( ':tracks_name', $tracks_name );
   $stmt->bindParam( ':album_id',    $album_id );

   // insert one row
   $album_id = $_POST["album_id"];
   $tracks_name = $_POST["tracks_name"];
   $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```